# Signature without slurping

Tags: perl, signature, subroutine-prototypes

This is a question about code that already works!  I have lots subroutines that take multiple arrays as inputs, such as:

```
use 5.24.0;
use feature 'refaliasing';
no warnings "experimental::refaliasing";
my (@foo,@bar,@baz);
sub sumarr (\@\@);

# other code to load arrays

sub sumarr (\@\@)
  { my (@sum, @aa, @ab);
    (\@aa,\@ab)=@_;
    $sum[$_] = $aa[$_] + $ab[$_] for 0 .. $#aa;
    return @sum;
    }
```

...which I can call simply with

```
@baz = sumarr( @foo, @bar);
```

I haven't  found any way to either replace the prototype with signatures, or at least augment the prototype with a signature for streamlining the argument list.  Is there anything that does that yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signatures unpack `@_` into lexical variables which are scoped to within the function. Prototypes affect how calls to the function are *parsed*. So they do different things — you can't just replace one with the other. (You can write a function that has both though.)

An illustration of prototypes affecting parsing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a = ( 1 );
my @b = ( 2 );

myfunc( @a, @b );

sub myfunc (\@\@) {
    print Dumper( @_ );
}

myfunc( @a, @b );
```

Notice that `myfunc` gets called twice with the same arguments, yet produces different outputs. With `use warnings`, Perl will at least warn you that you're doing something potentially weird.

As I mentioned, it is possible to declare both a signature and a prototype for the same function.

```
sub myfunc ( $A, $B ) :prototype(\@\@) {
    print Dumper( @_ );
}
```

(Signatures are still experimental, and I believe that they did recently switch the order the signature and prototype are declared! A reason to beware experimental features.)

TLDR: you can't replace prototypes with signatures, because they're different things.

Comment: Thanks -- that was the thing I was looking for:`sub whatsit ($v1, $v2) :prototype (\slurpy_sigil_1, \slurpy_sigil_2)`.  That makes calls to whatsit much more DWIMish.  A little extra dereferencing in whatsit and all is well.